# How to make a source package for a software in linux?

Tags: python, linux

I've already made a simple software with Python programming language. It has some libraries that I write and some executable files to work with program. I want to know how can I make an standard source package include documentation and install method for this software.

I know a little about `MakeFiles` but I don't know which standards I have to use for file structure and other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a real standard for the directory structure.

What *I* usually do is the following:

```
MyProject/
   |
   |
   |\ src/
   |   |
   |   |\ mypackage_1/
   |   |\ mypackage_2/
   |   |\ mymodule_1.py
   |    \ mymodule_2.py
   |
   |\ bin/
   |   |
   |   |\ my_script_1.py
   |    \ my_script_2.py
   |
   |\ doc/
   |   |
   |   |\ documentation_for_package_1/
   |   |\ documentation_for_package_2/
   |   |\ documentation_for_modules/
   |    \ documentation_for_scripts
   |
   |
    \ tests/
        |
        |\ tests_for_mypackage_1/
        |\ tests_for_mypackage_2/
        |\ tests_for_mymodule_1
        |\ tests_for_mymodule_2
         \ tests_for_scripts/
```

With this directory tree it should not be hard to install all the modules, packages etc. using setuptools or distribute. If you want to use only distutils, then I think this could be non-trivial.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the canonical documentation:

http://packages.python.org/distribute/setuptools.html

for building a proper package using setuptools that can 
be uploaded to PyPI or some other Python indexing server.

Comment: Thank you for this awesome reference. But it doesn't include information about proper directory structure. I have a bunch of files in a root directory and I think it's not a right way to distributing my package with this awful root director :D

Answer (score 1):

here's an example:

http://packages.python.org/an_example_pypi_project/setuptools.html